# Firebase Functions Count toward my GB bandwidth

Tags: function, cloud

I have wrote two functions in firebase, which maintain data. Like daily delete old data.

Question is when I write query to get data. does it count toward my GB downloaded limit which is $1/1GB for Blaze plan.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is transferred from Firebase Servers (Google Servers) to a user's computer (that is you in this case), you will be charged for all those data transfer into your computer.

Comment: I wrote Firebase Function. Data is not downloading to my machine. Firebase function is hosted by firebase on their server.

Comment: So do those function just delete the data? @VishalDesai

Comment: Yes.. It gets set from DB and go one by one and compare TS. and Delete. I confirmed with firebase. They are charging for DB bandwidth if you even get data from cloud functions. Thanks,

Comment: I have the same question with no authoritative answer.  If you got this from the firebase team you should write an answer and mark your own answer as correct.